# Multiple values are assigned to one variable. How does this work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angularjs specific code:

```
var deferred = $q.defer(),
    nextTransClass, prevTransClass;
```

What's the meaning of this? I have never seen such variable assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not all assigned to the same variable; they're just being declared on the same line.

The code above is equivalent o the following:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var nextTransClass;
var prevTransClass;
```

**P.S.** There's nothing Angular specific about this (besides for `$q.defer()`, obviously). This is just standard vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: @Joseph: in this case, what would be the type of "var"? would it have different types? (i think i'm missing something because i come from a strongly-typed background. :) )

Comment: @OJRaqueño - `var` does not indicate the type; it's just a generic form of variable declaration.